# Unable to update Datagrid and save changes to database

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, mvvm-light

I have a datagrid, an ObservableCollection of Product Types in a ViewModel and an implementation of EventToCommand like shown below.
I would like to update the Total Column from the product of Quantity and Cost Column and save the changes without using the evil code behind or Windows Forms DataGridView.
How can I achieve this?
Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="5,5,10,5" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="566"  >
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=Control}">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EndEdit}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Id"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Name"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cost" Binding="{Binding Path=Cost, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Cost"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Quantity"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="total" Binding="{Binding Path=Total, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Total"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Then in the ViewModel

```
 private ObservableCollection<Product> _product;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> MyProduct
    {
        get
        {
            return _product;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _product, value);
        }
    }

public ProductViewModel(IDataService proxy)
    {
        _proxy = proxy;

        LoadCommand = new RelayCommand(DoGetProducts);
        EndEdit = new RelayCommand<DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs>(DoEndEdit);

    }

    private void DoEndEdit(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs obj)
    {
        DataGridRow row = obj.Row;
        Product p = (Product)row.Item;
        p.Total = p.Cost*p.Quantity;
        _proxy.SaveAll();
    }
```

Then in the Model:

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    ProductEntities context;
    public DataService()
    {
        context = new ProductEntities();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Product> GetProducts(){
        ObservableCollection<Product> products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
            foreach(var p in context.Products.Tolist()){
                products.add(p);
            }
        return products;
    }
    public void SaveAll()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The datagrid is loading products but not updating the Total when Cost and Quantity is changed. Also, not saving the changes in database

Comment: If your models Total setter is implementing the INotifyPropertChanged interface (this is not shown) then the only suggestion I thing I can think of is adding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to you binding.

Comment: Why do you bind your `DataGrid` `ItemsSource` to a  property named `ExamsList` when there is no such property in the ViewModel? Or do you forget this property in your example?

Comment: @SebastianRichter that's a typo. However, it's not where the problem is coming from

Comment: @stuicidle the model comes from an entity data model

Comment: Your problem is solved finally. No need to code at all. See the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The output will be like this:-
>   [image]

Change your Xaml like give below

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="5,5,10,5" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="566"  >
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding" ">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EndEdit}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Id"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Name"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cost" Binding="{Binding Path=Cost, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Cost"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Quantity"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="total" Binding="{Binding Path=Total, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Total"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

**And in View Model you Bindings be like**

```
public BindingList<Product> ProductList
{
 get
  {
   return _proxy.ProductList;
  }
}
```

**And EndEdit Command Should execute the following function**

```
private void ExecuteEndEdit(DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs param)
 {
  var product  = param.Row.Item as Product; 
  var result = ProductList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == product.Id);
  var index= ProductList.IndexOf(result);
  result.Total = result.Cost * result.Quantity;
  ProductList.ResetItem(index);
 }
```

**Your IDataService can Expose Binding List like**

```
  public class DataService : IDataService
    {
        ProductEntities context;
        public DataService()
        {
            context = new ProductEntities();
        }
        public BindingList<Product> ProductList
        {
            get
            {
               //EDIT: YOU HAVE TO CALL context.Products.Load(); OR IT WILL RETURN EMPTY RESULTS
               context.Products.Load();
                return context.Products.Local.ToBindingList<Product>();
            }
        }
        public void SaveAll()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

> The Context.Save will save your code.

Comment: Please refactor as per your need. :)

Comment: can anybody explain why. its marked not as answer without testing.  this is working solution

Comment: Let me test the code I will mark it as answer soon ignore the downvoters

Comment: how do you initialize the ProductList because `ProductList = new new BindingList<Product>();` and `ProductList =context.Products.Local.ToBindingList<Product>();` doesn't seem to work while 

     `foreach (var p in context.Products)
            {
               ProductsList.Add(p);
        }` seems to add each item twice and does not save on `context.SaveChanges()`

Comment: no I don't initialize it. You just directly take  context.Products.Local.ToBindingList<Product>(); no need to create it in IdataService. Just Expose the real collection from data service. It will ensure consistency

Comment: you can expose via  dataservice

Comment: Updating answer as per your convenience

Comment: I Get that. However my binding datacontext for the view is the viewmodel and the Property ProductList and EventToCommand is defined in the VM. So Now I have a Method prototype in IDataService Called `BindingList<Product>GetProducts()` and implemented in DataService as 
    `public BindingList<Product> GetProducts(){
return context.Products.Local.ToBindingList<Product>();
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152498/discussion-between-martin-kariuki-and-ramankingdom).

Comment: @Ramankingdom
**1.** Why is `cmd` taken from `<cmd:EventToCommand`?
What is this namespace?
**2.** You can add the `EndEdit` command from the line `<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EndEdit}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>`

Answer (score 2):

For the "total" column in the `DataGrid` to get updated, the `Product` class should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Total` property:

```
private double _total;
public double Total
{
    get { return _total; }
    set { _total = value; OnPropertyChanged("Total"); }
}
```

And for you to be able to save the value to the database, you need to map the `Total` property against a column in your database table, just like you (hopefully) did with the other columns.

Comment: First of all, I cannot bind to single property because it's a list of items. Also, in MVVM light, the `Set(ref, _property,value)` implements the INotifyPropertChanged.

Comment: You are already binding to a singel property in your DataGridTextColumn...and it is the setter of the Total property of the Product class that should call the Set method, not the MyProduct property.

Comment: This Item i am binding to comes from an observable collection of items like `ObservableCollection<Product>` so when i'm binding i bind to a property of an item from the collection like `Product.Price`. Do I need to create another single item and if so, how will data be loaded to the grid? I might be missing something from your answer.

Comment: When you set the Total property of Product, the total column in your DataGrid will display this value only if the Product class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise the PropertyChanged event in the setter of the Total property as I stated in my answer. Whether the ItemsSource property is bound to an ObservableCollection doesn't matter.